# React native expo error getting location with Deadline_Exceeded?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am simply trying to convert an address into geolocation latitude and longitude in my react native project. I am getting below error .

> Error getting location [Error: Call to function
> 'ExpoLocation.geocodeAsync' has been rejected. → Caused by:
> java.io.IOException: fmow: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: ClientCall started after
> CallOptions deadline was exceeded. Deadline has been exceeded for
> 1.594758711s. ]

reat native code is as below

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.error('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
  
      try {
        const geocodedLocation = await Location.geocodeAsync("Bahnhofstrasse 1 Zürich 8001 ch");
        if (geocodedLocation.length > 0) {
          const { latitude, longitude } = geocodedLocation[0];
          setLocation({
            latitude: geocodedLocation[0].latitude,
            longitude: geocodedLocation[0].longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          });
          a = geocodedLocation[0].latitude;
          b = geocodedLocation[0].longitude;
        }
  
        const { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setRegion({
          latitude: coords.latitude,
          longitude: coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        });
        c = coords.latitude;
        d = coords.longitude;
        setCoords([
          { latitude: a, longitude: b },
          { latitude: c, longitude: d },
        ]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting location', error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```